# UWP hangs when loading Rich Text document as embedded resource

Tags: file-io, uwp, embedded-resource

I'm trying to include some rich text with my app, but the app hangs when trying to load the text.

```
// Here is the initiating call:
await aboutDialog.ShowAsync();

// This code hangs on the second line
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("XamlSandbox.cities.rtf");
    myRichEditBox.Document.LoadFromStream(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
}

// This code works OK
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    myRichEditBox.Document.LoadFromStream(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, fileStream);
}
```

I've tried loading the embedded resource into a memory stream and using that, but that hangs too.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to properly load the embedded resource in UWP:

```
            var rtfUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///cities.rtf");
            var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(rtfUri);
            var stream = file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            myRichEditBox.Document.LoadFromStream(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, stream.GetResults());
```

Comment: Nice to see you solved the problem, please mark it as an answer so it can help more people